# Is it possible to refresh ENV during runtime

Tags: ruby, dotenv

I am using the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) Gem to read variables in my .env file. I created a console command that updates the .env file, but also in the same runtime, it reads them.  The problem is that it reads the old values, even though I updated the .env file.  Is there a way to refresh the ENV during runtime so it gets the latest values?

.env

```rb
FOOBAR=hello
```

ruby.rb

```rb
puts ENV['FOOBAR'] # Prints "hello"
EnvFile.update_variable('.env', 'FOOBAR', "How are you?")
Dotenv.load('.env')
puts ENV['FOOBAR'] # Prints "hello" even though looking in .env it has the new value "How are you?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refresh with the following:

```
Dotenv.overload('.env')
```

Thank you domcermak for answering this at: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/426

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are using `dotenv`?  `rbenv` manages ruby installs and doesn't read `.env` from what I searched in the source code.  With dotenv, you can reload ENV from the `.env` file by calling `Dotenv.load`.  It's probably going to give you warnings about constants being redefined.  What I would do is make a config class to combine the default settings from ENV with the redefining feature/function you want.  Config manages everything but reads defaults from `.env`.

Comment: Thank you. I did mean dotenv.  I updated the question and added some code. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.